# Find and replace text in a webpage with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, dom

I am new to web development and would like to get feedback on a JavaScript library that automatically finds and replaces text on a webpage using the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) interface.

EDIT: Seeing that this has gone a week unanswered I've cut out non-essential code to reduce the line count from 300 to more manageable 150.

The [README](https://github.com/DanielZTing/TextObserver/blob/master/README.md) may also be helpful in understanding how it is meant to be used. My main questions are:

- As you might have inferred from the heavy use of private variables, I have a Java background. Is such usage of OOP/encapsulation idiomatic in JS?
- To prevent replacements made by one observer's callback from alerting other observers and creating an infinite "ping-pong" effect, I store every created `TextObserver` in a static class variable and deactivate them before running the callback. Is this good practice? It feels like a [God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).
- Is there anything else I should do to make this more fit for use as a library? ([UMD?](https://github.com/umdjs/umd)) And is the README understandable? (If it is appropriate to ask for reviews on documentation here.)

```javascript
class TextObserver {
    #target;
    #callback;
    #observer;
    // Sometimes, MutationRecords of type 'childList' have added nodes with overlapping subtrees
    // Nodes can also be removed and reattached from one parent to another
    // This can cause resource usage to explode with "recursive" replacements, e.g. expands -> physically expands
    // The processed set ensures that each added node is only processed once so the above doesn't happen
    #processed = new Set();

    // Keep track of all created observers to prevent infinite callbacks
    static #observers = new Set();

    // Use static read-only properties as class constants
    static get #IGNORED_NODES() {
        // Node types that implement the CharacterData interface but are not relevant or visible to the user
        return [Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE, Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE, Node.COMMENT_NODE];
    }
    static get #IGNORED_TAGS() {
        // Text nodes that are not front-facing content
        return ['SCRIPT', 'STYLE', 'NOSCRIPT'];
    }
    static get #CONFIG() {
        return {
            subtree: true,
            childList: true,
            characterData: true,
            characterDataOldValue: true,
        };
    }

    constructor(callback, target = document, processExisting = true) {
        this.#callback = callback;

        // If target is entire document, manually process <title> and skip the rest of the <head>
        // Processing the <head> can increase runtime by a factor of two
        if (target === document) {
            document.title = callback(document.title);
            // Sometimes <body> may be missing, like when viewing an .SVG file in the browser
            if (document.body !== null) {
                target = document.body;
            } else {
                console.warn('Document body does not exist, exiting...');
                return;
            }

        }
        this.#target = target;

        if (processExisting) {
            TextObserver.#flushAndSleepDuring(() => this.#processNodes(target));
        }

        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            const records = [];
            for (const textObserver of TextObserver.#observers) {
                // This ternary is why this section does not use flushAndSleepDuring
                // It allows the nice-to-have property of callbacks being processed in the order they were declared
                records.push(textObserver === this ? mutations : textObserver.#observer.takeRecords());
                textObserver.#observer.disconnect();
            }
            let i = 0;
            for (const textObserver of TextObserver.#observers) {
                textObserver.#observerCallback(records[i]);
                i++;
            }

            TextObserver.#observers.forEach(textObserver => textObserver.#observer.observe(textObserver.#target, TextObserver.#CONFIG));
        });
        observer.observe(target, TextObserver.#CONFIG);

        this.#observer = observer;
        TextObserver.#observers.add(this);
    }

    #observerCallback(mutations) {
        for (const mutation of mutations) {
            const target = mutation.target;
            switch (mutation.type) {
                case 'childList':
                    for (const node of mutation.addedNodes) {
                        if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                            if (this.#valid(node) && !this.#processed.has(node)) {
                                node.nodeValue = this.#callback(node.nodeValue);
                                this.#processed.add(node);
                            }
                        } else if (!TextObserver.#IGNORED_NODES.includes(node.nodeType)) {
                            // If added node is not text, process subtree
                            this.#processNodes(node);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 'characterData':
                    if (this.#valid(target) && target.nodeValue !== mutation.oldValue) {
                        target.nodeValue = this.#callback(target.nodeValue);
                        this.#processed.add(target);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static #flushAndSleepDuring(callback) {
        // Disconnect all other observers to prevent infinite callbacks
        const records = [];
        for (const textObserver of TextObserver.#observers) {
            // Collect pending mutation notifications
            records.push(textObserver.#observer.takeRecords());
            textObserver.#observer.disconnect();
        }
        // This is in its own separate loop from the above because we want to disconnect everything before proceeding
        // Otherwise, the mutations in the callback may trigger the other observers
        let i = 0;
        for (const textObserver of TextObserver.#observers) {
            textObserver.#observerCallback(records[i]);
            i++;
        }
        callback();
        TextObserver.#observers.forEach(textObserver => textObserver.#observer.observe(textObserver.#target, TextObserver.#CONFIG));
    }

    #valid(node) {
        return (
            // Sometimes the node is removed from the document before we can process it, so check for valid parent
            node.parentNode !== null
            && !TextObserver.#IGNORED_NODES.includes(node.nodeType)
            && !TextObserver.#IGNORED_TAGS.includes(node.parentNode.tagName)
            // Ignore contentEditable elements as touching them messes up the cursor position
            && !node.parentNode.isContentEditable
            // HACK: workaround to avoid breaking icon fonts
            && !window.getComputedStyle(node.parentNode).getPropertyValue('font-family').toUpperCase().includes('ICON')
        );
    }

    #processNodes(root) {
        // Process valid Text nodes
        const nodes = document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, { acceptNode: node => (
            this.#valid(node) && !this.#processed.has(node)) ? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT
        });
        while (nodes.nextNode()) {
            nodes.currentNode.nodeValue = this.#callback(nodes.currentNode.nodeValue);
            this.#processed.add(nodes.currentNode);
        }
    }
}

// A good page to try this out on would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heck
const badWordFilter = new TextObserver(text => text.replaceAll(/heck/gi, 'h*ck'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a short review;

- Classes are idiomatic (and becoming more so over time), but the heavy usage of private variables makes the code harder to read for me.
- For production code, I would drop calls to `console.warn()` it does not seem warranted here
- Unless you are worried about observers not managed in `TextObserver`, I would have a static in your class called `sleepMode`, and in your mutation observer you leave immediately if sleepMode is on. To me that would be KISS and remove the Gode Mode problem.
- The name of `TextObserver` is not great, it is meant to replace text which is not clear from the name
- In the README, I would follow the [Mozilla format/approach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for the replacement function you pass instead of just `a function that takes a string as its only argument and returns a string to replace it with`
- I would add a feature where an observer can have a list/array of functions to apply so that the event needs to be processed only once and then have something like

  ```
   const grammarPolice = new TextObserver(text => text.replaceAll(/would of/gi, 'would have'));
   grammarPolice.add(text => text.replaceAll(/should of/gi, 'should have'));
  ```
- Comments are good, but some of them are too much like `// Use static read-only properties as class constants`
- I would have called `valid` -> `isValid`

Overall, my first impression was that this looked indeed like a Java coder writing, but really after a closer look, this is just battled tested code.